# CSS Showing on Every Other Element

Tags: html, css

I have an effect that I'm trying to reproduce, a subtle shadow under an element.

I have a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/y22L0qnx/) that illustrates what I'm trying to accomplish.

This bit of code makes the shadow, but awkwardly enough it only appears on select elements, and even adjusts when the window is resized and then appears on different elements.

```
.an-emotion::after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 2px;
  width: 0.7%;
  left: -4%;
  margin: 0 0 0 50%;
  transform: rotateX(45deg) scale(10, .75);
  background: #000;
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px #000, 0 0 2px #000, 0 0 3px #000, 0 0 5px #000, 0 0 5px #000, 0 0 5px #000, 0 0 7px #000, 0 0 12px #000;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add a `min-width` of 1px to your css rules for `.an-emotion::after` to solve this.

So just change it to

```css
.an-emotion::after {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    height: 2px;
    width: 0.7%;
    min-width:1px;  /*add this line*/
    left: -4%;
    margin: 0 0 0 50%;
    transform: rotateX(45deg) scale(10, .75);
    background: #000;
    box-shadow: 0 0 1px #000, 0 0 2px #000, 0 0 3px #000, 0 0 5px #000, 0 0 5px #000, 0 0 5px #000, 0 0 7px #000, 0 0 12px #000;
}
```

Heres an example:

```css
.emotion-rows {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 30px;
}
.a-row {
  padding: 0px 1%;
  position: relative;
  width: 99%;
  height: 30px;
  margin: 0px auto 10px;
}
.an-emotion {
  height: 25px;
  line-height: 28px;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: "Oriya";
  font-size: 15px;
  width: 8.5%;
  float: left;
  margin: 0px 2px;
  // box-shadow: inset 0px -1px 5px 4px rgba(0, 0, 80, 0.01);
  background-color: rgba(27, 45, 115, 0.01);
  transition: all 250ms linear;
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
}
.the-word {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
}
.the-word:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all 150ms linear;
  top: -4px;
}
.an-emotion::after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 2px;
  width: 0.7%;
  min-width:1px;
  left: -4%;
  margin: 0 0 0 50%;
  transform: rotateX(45deg) scale(10, .75);
  background: #000;
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px #000, 0 0 2px #000, 0 0 3px #000, 0 0 5px #000, 0 0 5px #000, 0 0 5px #000, 0 0 7px #000, 0 0 12px #000;
  opacity: 0.15;
}
```

```html
<div class="emotion-rows">
  <div class="a-row row1">
    <div class="an-emotion">
      <div class="the-word">JOY</div>
    </div>
    <div class="an-emotion">
      <div class="the-word">LIFE</div>
    </div>
    <div class="an-emotion">
      <div class="the-word">GIVING</div>
    </div>
    <div class="an-emotion">
      <div class="the-word">THINK</div>
    </div>
    <div class="an-emotion">
      <div class="the-word">RIGHT</div>
    </div>
    <div class="an-emotion">
      <div class="the-word">YES</div>
    </div>
    <div class="an-emotion">
      <div class="the-word">HI</div>
    </div>
    <div class="an-emotion">
      <div class="the-word">BEHAPPY</div>
    </div>
    <div class="an-emotion">
      <div class="the-word">LIFELESS</div>
    </div>
    <div class="an-emotion">
      <div class="the-word">NO</div>
    </div>
    <div class="an-emotion">
      <div class="the-word">AGAIN</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="a-row row2">
    <div class="an-emotion">
      <div class="the-word">GIVING</div>
    </div>
    <div class="an-emotion">
      <div class="the-word">INSPIRATIONAL</div>
    </div>
    <div class="an-emotion">
      <div class="the-word">YEP</div>
    </div>
    <div class="an-emotion">
      <div class="the-word">LIFE</div>
    </div>
    <div class="an-emotion">
      <div class="the-word">HATE</div>
    </div>
    <div class="an-emotion">
      <div class="the-word">VICIOUS</div>
    </div>
    <div class="an-emotion">
      <div class="the-word">WATER</div>
    </div>
    <div class="an-emotion">
      <div class="the-word">RIGHTEOUS</div>
    </div>
    <div class="an-emotion">
      <div class="the-word">GIVING</div>
    </div>
    <div class="an-emotion">
      <div class="the-word">BROKEN</div>
    </div>
    <div class="an-emotion">
      <div class="the-word">INSPIRED</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Where he need to add `min-width`? elaborate your answer more.

Comment: Absolutely what I needed. Thank you. Can you elaborate on why this is needed, and why it only affected certain elements?

Comment: `// box-shadow: inset 0px` is not a CSS comment. You work too much with SASS :D

Comment: I think its aktually `/* Comment */`. Thx for reminding me. havn't noticed it